# How to create new property and initialize values on "window" from Android JavaScript bridge?

Tags: android, typescript

I have question about how I can intialize property on window from Android JavaScript bridge.

I have web-server code that defines typescript interface as:

```
export interface Context {
  readonly theme?: string;
  readonly sessionId?: string;
  readonly appSessionId?: string;
}
```

this object is accessed within typescript code as

```
export const getMyAppContext: GetMyAppContext = () => (window as any).appContext as Context;
```

in typescript this object can initialized as say,

```
(window as any).appContext = {
  theme: 'default',
  sessionId: 'session-id',
  appSessionId: 'app-session-id',
};
```

Now I attempt to do the same from Android java-script bridge as:

```
evaluateJavascript("javascript:window.appContext = { appSessionId: '1234', theme: 'dark',};")
```

However, when server code attempts to access this window.appContext property as say

```
const { theme } = getMyAppContext();
```

I see the error *TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'theme' of 'window.appContext' as it is undefined."*

How can I make sure appContext property on window is initialized correctly from javaScript bridge associated with the webview?